# filter out e-mail addresses in boolean searches

Tags: mysql

I'm constructing a database with photo's. 
By using a boolean search I get the right images for the used search(phrase).

Now I have this problem:
In many of the descriptions the email address of the person or subject is marked. Like **my.name@telenet.be**
Now, when I want to find an image of the **company Telenet**, I get all the records that contain a email address of the provider. Who are of no imporatance of my search.

Here is a example of my search:

```
SELECT ID,auteur, title, datetaken, description,
keywords,thumbnail,URL,rel_date,showa,initialen,type
FROM archief
WHERE MATCH(description, keywords) AGAINST(' +telenet ' IN BOOLEAN
MODE) AND rechten <> '0' AND showa = '1' AND type >= '2' AND rel_date
<= '20120921' ORDER BY datetaken desc LIMIT 60'
in 'where clause'
```

What can I do to filter out the searchphrase containing an `@` symbol?

Comment: Why do not you want to filtering out string using `instr` function and pattern: `"@" + company_name + '.'` ? You can even create column and apply index on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try REGEXP operator, in your cause it will look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM archief
WHERE
    description REGEXP '[^@]telenet' OR
    keywords REGEXP '[^@]telenet'
```

This query should select all records which contain `telenet` string without preceding `@` in `description` or `keywords` fields.